# Insert checkbox value in database on check without Submit php/javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to insert the values of a checkbox into my database just on checking the box.
Please let me know what's wrong with the code.
I've made it as simple as possible, to understand, as i'm just learning how jquery/js/php integrate together.
Thanks

This is the HTML

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function(){
   var checked = $(this).attr('checked');
   if(checked){
      var value = $(this).val();
      $.post('promo.php', { value:value }, function(data){
          // data = 0 - means that there was an error
          // data = 1 - means that everything is ok
          if(data == 1){
             // Do something or do nothing :-)
             alert('Data was saved in db!');
          }
      });
   }
});
});
</script>    


 </head> 
 
 <body>
   
<form method="post" name="form1">     
<input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="1">
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

And this is promo.php where the function should perform the magic :)

```
<?php
if ($_POST && isset($_POST['value'])) {

    // db connection
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
    if (!$link) {
       // error happened
       print(0);
    }
    mysql_select_db('my_db');

    // sanitize the value
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['value']);

    // start the query
    $sql = "INSERT INTO promo (id_model, id_storage, olx, google, fb) VALUES ('$value','$value','$value','$value','$value')";

    // check if the query was executed
    if(mysql_query($sql, $link)){
       // everything is Ok, the data was inserted
       print(1);    
    } else {
       // error happened
       print(0);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: And what do you see?  Does your onClick function run?

Comment: No error... can't see anything...

Comment: Could you add a var_dump($_POST) as the first line in your php file so you can see exactly what you are sending as the only way of your not seeing anything would appear to be that the if conditions aren't being met.

Comment: @Haworth What should i see? I tried but can't see anything :(

Comment: **`mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0**, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. You could use [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension instead.

Comment: i've changed mysql with mysqli but doesn't solve the issue. The thing is that i don't think it reaches the php file, because i have changed the connection password and there is no error alert